# Coin Toss Gambling Game

Tags: probability, gambling

This question appears in several books written (or co-written) by Robert L. Scheaffer.

Two gamblers bet 1 dollar each on the successive tosses of a coin. Each has a bank of 6 dollars.

(a) What is the probability that they break even after six tosses?

(b) What is the probability that one player, say Jones, wins all the money on the tenth toss of the coin?

I have no problem with (a) and after much thought (and some help) I
have gotten the "right" answer (which is in the book) for (b). But I have some doubts about the (b) answer. That answer is: $\frac{27}{1024}$, which is $$\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{2}{0} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{1024}$$
The numerator makes sense to me because Jones must have two losses at least one of which 
must be during the first six tosses, and if only one is during the first six, the other must 
be during the seventh or eighth toss. But I have some doubts about the denominator, which
counts *all* possible win/loss events for ten tosses. However, if (say) Jones wins on the sixth 
toss, the game ends, so why do we count the subsequent tosses, which I call "phantom" tosses?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the reason is that you must have equally likely events for the simple division of cases to work.

A sequence which ends after 6 turns such as Jones winning all these turns has probability $\frac{1}{2^6}$. If, however, we count all the possibilities for 10 turns (using your nicely phrased "phantom" turns) then we are in effect considering this to have probability  $\frac{2^4}{2^{10}}$. There's no difference re. the maths.

P.S. It has just occurred to me that Fermat solved a gambling problem using just this way of considering events and the issue you have raised was questioned at the time.

Comment: I don't think this is the best explanation.  We are only considering events that consist of $10$ tosses, each of which has probability $2^{-10}$.  The case where one player wins all the money in $6$ tosses doesn't enter in at all.

Comment: The event you mention is one of the 1024 events in the denominator. You are of course right that one can consider probabilities instead of equally likely events. However, I have reread the question and it does seem to be being asked in the spirit of the approach I have used.

Comment: Thank you, S. Dolan. I hope you (or someone else) can tell me where I can find Fermat's discussion of this (especially an English translation). Knowing that Fermat considered this, I now have no doubt that, at least, my question was reasonable.

Comment: As an initial reference you might like to check out the Problem of Points on Wikipedia. "The starting insight ...[depended on] ... the possible ways the game **might** have continued, were it not interrupted."" I believe that Pascal had problems with this idea but Fermat took what we might think of as the 'correct' viewpoint and verified the answers Pascal had obtained but in which he lacked confidence. So, yes, you are indeed in good company in wanting to think deeply about these ideas rather than just accepting a (now) standard viewpoint.